# CSS: style nth sibling

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to style the nth sibling in pure CSS?
For example, can we style 4-th or 5-th `.child` when hover on 1-st `.child`?

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"> 1 </div>
    <div class="child"> 2 </div>
    <div class="child"> 3 </div>
    <div class="child"> 4 </div>
    <div class="child"> 5 </div>
</div>
```

**update** I guess my question was not correct a bit. Excuse me for that.

I meant can I style nth sibling of a .child that I hovered on?

I.e. style 4-th `.child` when hover on 1-st `.child`; style 5-th `.child` when hover on 2-nd, etc.

Comment: There are only 5 children, so there is no "etc" to speak of, unless there is an additional requirement you haven't mentioned.

Comment: @BoltClock, I meant there could be **more** elements

Comment: I don't think there is currently a way of shortening `+*+*+*+*`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Sure you can. You use the [general sibling selector (~)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) in combination with `:hover`.

```css
.child:first-of-type:hover ~ .child:nth-of-type(4) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"> 1 </div>
    <div class="child"> 2 </div>
    <div class="child"> 3 </div>
    <div class="child"> 4 </div>
    <div class="child"> 5 </div>
</div>
```

> The ~ combinator separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it is preceded by the first, and both share a common parent.

#### UPDATE

> update I guess my question was not correct a bit. Excuse me for that.
>
> I meant **can I style nth sibling of hovered .child**?

No, since as far as I know there's no way for "counting siblings".
You could work-around the problem, say you want to highlight the second sibling of each `.child` when hovering.

```css
.child:nth-of-type(1):hover ~ .child:nth-of-type(3) {
  color: red;
}

.child:nth-of-type(2):hover ~ .child:nth-of-type(4) {
  color: red;
}

.child:nth-of-type(3):hover ~ .child:nth-of-type(5) {
  color: red;
}

.child:nth-of-type(4):hover ~ .child:nth-of-type(6) {
  color: red;
}

.child:nth-of-type(5):hover ~ .child:nth-of-type(7) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"> 1 </div>
    <div class="child"> 2 </div>
    <div class="child"> 3 </div>
    <div class="child"> 4 </div>
    <div class="child"> 5 </div>
</div>
```

To simplify this task, you may want to use a preprocessor like SASS:

```
@each $i in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) {
  .child:nth-of-type(#{$i}):hover ~ .child:nth-of-type(#{$i + 2}) {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

which would generate above CSS.

Comment: I've updated the question, look at it pls.

Comment: @Zurab-D see my updated answer.

Comment: I suppose the solution with SASS is acceptable enough in this case even it is not complete. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sure we can

```css
.child:nth-child(1):hover ~ .child:nth-child(4),
.child:nth-child(1):hover ~ .child:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"> 1 </div>
    <div class="child"> 2 </div>
    <div class="child"> 3 </div>
    <div class="child"> 4 </div>
    <div class="child"> 5 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've updated the question, look at it pls.

Comment: @Zurab-D I've seen it, that's a big difference from before. Don't know if this is possible with pure CSS ...

Answer (score 1):

```css
.child {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3em;
}

.child:first-child:hover~.child:nth-child(4),
.child:first-child:hover~.child:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"> 1 </div>
  <div class="child"> 2 </div>
  <div class="child"> 3 </div>
  <div class="child"> 4 </div>
  <div class="child"> 5 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've updated the question, look at it pls.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible, you can use "nth-child(index)"

CSS

```
.parent .child:nth-child(3):hover{
  background-color:red;
}
```

3 is the index of the child.
Thank Me later.

Comment: I've updated the question, look at it pls.